# NSPredicate with array not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nspredicate

I'm trying to figure out why is this code is not showing the same results and also why the two string are not equal. The value I insert into the UITextfield is "a" as you can see in the logs.

```
- (void)resultsForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{   
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a"];

    NSLog(@"searchString = %@", searchString);
    NSLog(@"str = %@", str);

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nick", @"Ben", @"Adam", @"Melissa", nil];

    NSPredicate *aPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", searchString];
    NSArray *beginWithA = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aPredicate];
    NSLog(@"%@", beginWithA);

    aPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", str];
    beginWithA = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aPredicate];
    NSLog(@"%@", beginWithA);

    if ([str isEqualToString:searchString]) {
        NSLog(@"true");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"false");
    }
}
```

This method is called like this as a trigger for UIControlEventEditingChanged:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)sender
{
    [self resultsForSearchString:sender.text];
}
```

Here is the output:

```
2013-12-17 16:44:49.845 SevenOut[7381:70b] searchString = ​a 
2013-12-17 16:44:49.846 SevenOut[7381:70b] str = a
2013-12-17 16:44:52.676 SevenOut[7381:70b] (
)
2013-12-17 16:44:53.956 SevenOut[7381:70b] (
    Adam
)
2013-12-17 16:44:54.988 SevenOut[7381:70b] false
```

Comment: Your code is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your code and it works fine.

```
2013-12-17 15:02:45.778 MessAbout[3856:70b] searchString = a | length = 1
2013-12-17 15:02:45.779 MessAbout[3856:70b] str = a | length = 1
2013-12-17 15:02:45.779 MessAbout[3856:70b] (
    Adam
)
2013-12-17 15:02:45.779 MessAbout[3856:70b] (
    Adam
)
2013-12-17 15:02:45.780 MessAbout[3856:70b] true
```

If you change your first 2 logs to

```
NSLog(@"searchString = %@ | length = %u", searchString, [searchString length]);
NSLog(@"str = %@ | length = %u", str, [str length]);
```

Then you'll probably see why they're not the same string.

Comment: After the modifications I can see that something is tampering with that string. Here's my output. Thanks for the info.

2013-12-17 17:12:22.418 SevenOut[7532:70b] searchString = ​a | lenght 2
2013-12-17 17:12:22.419 SevenOut[7532:70b] str = a | lenght 1
2013-12-17 17:12:46.161 SevenOut[7532:70b] (
)
2013-12-17 17:12:46.755 SevenOut[7532:70b] (
    Adam
)
2013-12-17 17:12:47.562 SevenOut[7532:70b] false

Comment: @MariusFanu why searchString length is equal to 2? i'm interested to this question thanks

Comment: @Ilario, I use JSTokenField and it seems that they do some init to the textField property with this "\u200B" and somehow and mess with it from the beginning.